# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" IntelliJ issue

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am getting this error in my IntelliJ program:
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Feature: Shout

From research, it looks like I am missing JAR files, updating the class path etc.
Some answers say to add dependencies in the Maven POM, so I've done this, hit "build" and reran the feature file with the same results.
Some answers also say to add the jar file but I am really unfamiliar with Java IDEs and not a developer. I've googled how to add a jar file and most answers tell me to go to Project structure in IntelliJ. In artifacts part of Project Structure, I hit "+" and I see an option to Create jar from modules but this popup is really confusing. I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with it. I've also downloaded the SLF4J jar files but I don't know how to get them in IntellJ. Create JAR from Modules doesn't seem to have a link to the desktop to import anything. Creating jar from empty results in another screen that doesn't seem to have any link to the desktop. Other results say to add a jar file from the + sign under modules and this also doesn't seem to give any option. I'm also not sure how big a problem this is because running my feature file results in the incorrect output and may regardless of this issue.

Here's my POM, then:

```
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



<groupId>cucumber-school</groupId>

<artifactId>shouty</artifactId>

<version>0.0.1</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Shouty</name>



<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

    <cucumber.version>2.3.1</cucumber.version>

    <cucumber.pro.version>2.0.4</cucumber.pro.version>

    <maven.compiler.version>3.3</maven.compiler.version>

</properties>



<dependencies>

    <dependency>

        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>

        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>

        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>

        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>



    <dependency>

        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>

        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>

        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>

        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>



    <dependency>

        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>

        <artifactId>pro-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>${cucumber.pro.version}</version>

        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>



    <dependency>

        <groupId>junit</groupId>

        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

        <version>${junit.version}</version>

        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Since you recognize that you're missing a jar file, and that the dependencies in your pom file should fix it, but hasn't, you likely did something wrong in your pom. Don't you think that showing us the pom file, so we might help you figure out what you did wrong, might be a useful thing? **Show your POM!**

Comment: i would say you probably have something conflicting on the classpath. you have the jar you need but another class in the classload is being found first. i've had this problem before. go to your dependency hierarchy and find out what's being in another log4 adn then add an exclusion to your pom

Comment: Do you understand the explanation at https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder ?

Comment: I've read it and it says to add slfj4 to the classpath but I don't know how to make that happen in IntelliJ. I know how to add Jars in eclipse. And I've adjusted the pom file as above.

Comment: Also I'm very confused on this classpath issue. I keep going to project structure > Artifacts > + sign > Jars but I don't understand what I'm supposed to do at this point. Other answers say to just add the jar files but the only options I see are to create an unnamed (something)? I can't even tell what it's creating. I assume it's trying to create a jar file from scratch. But I'm asking it to import. There is a button for "create manifest' and 'use existing manifest' and that's unclear, also. I've googled this now for three days and I'm still incredibly confused.

Answer (score 22):

Adding this here in the hope that it will help someone else somewhere along the line. I am using IntelliJ on a Mac. Initially, I was getting the "Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder message" so I added the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Note that the versions should be changed to the desired one for each. After this I began getting the "No SLF4J providers were found" error message. I had to go to File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies tab -> Select the two dependencies -> Make sure their scope is "Compile" not "Test" -> Click "Apply" -> Click "OK".[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, my problem was because of scope "Test" not "Compile"

Comment: yes, thank you, I had it right there in the dependency as well as you: 
<scope>test</scope>

Comment: in case of Gradle, if someone is trying to use the logger in the main program, then make sure it is "compile" and not "testCompile".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to build a project scala 2.11 with maven, but the solution of adding dependancies did not help.
Removing scala.sdk.2.11.12 from Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the version compatibilities of slf4j libraries which will get downloaded while setting up other jars. Keep below in your pom.xml and It will disable all the warnings/errors from slf4j. It worked for me

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-alpha6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you find it confusing to find POM.xml try to check the available update of your IntelliJ IDE then try to Update it. During the updating process, the new version of IntelliJ will show issues that need to be fixed (including missing jar file or classpath conflict).